# Pandas DataFrame with Bars

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame. Is there any way to add those bars on the dataFrame?

[image]

For example if the code would be like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3], [3, 7], [4, 1]], columns = [A, B])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do that, as a pandas [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) is a data structure, thus it has to be constituted or built by numpy arrays, a dict, or DataFrame. What you can do is generate a bar plot and add text to it from the dataframe values.

Comment: Thank you for the answer